# vb.net vs2010 project deployment problem: eula.rtf is not displayed during application deployment. Any ideas?

Tags: vb.net, deployment, eula

I've created a setup and deployment project for my vb.net application using the Visual Studio 2010 wizard. I also added the eula.rtf file to the setup project and set it to install to the user's application folder. I then added a license agreement UI dialog in the setup project and pointed the licenseFile to eula.rtf. However, when testing the resulting setup.msi, the UI License Agreement dialog appears but no text is displayed inside the box where the eula should appear. I tried re-naming the eula and tried to change the encoding of the file but without success. Am I missing something? What should I do to make it work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually create a .rtf in the proper format or did you just rename a text file?  You'll need either Wordpad or Microsoft Word to create one.  Wordpad is the better choice, it is likelier to create RTF in a format that the rich text box fully supports.